# Delete None values from Python dict

Tags: python

Newbie to Python, so this may seem silly.

I have two dicts:

```
default = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta', 'g': 'Gamma'}
user = {'a': 'NewAlpha', 'b': None}
```

I need to update my defaults with the values that exist in user.  But only for those that have a value not equal to None.  So I need to get back a new dict:

```
result = {'a': 'NewAlpha', 'b': 'beta', 'g': 'Gamma'}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
result = default.copy()
result.update((k, v) for k, v in user.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

Comment: And in Python 3, use user.items()

Answer (score 7):

With the `update()` method, and some generator expression:

```
D.update((k, v) for k, v in user.iteritems() if v is not None)
```